# Latest Vaadin SpringBoot application built with Gradle tries to go offline by default

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, vaadin, vaadin-flow

After successfully building the application with Gradle, the application fails to output the views properly on the local host. The page says: "**App ready.**"  But then it outputs "**Cannot GET /offline-stub.html**".

I know that Vaadin now allows creating offline web apps, but this is NOT what I need. I want to get the front end working and outputting everything ONLINE.

Here is some output from the compilation:

> ------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
> 2021-11-01 16:44:04.208  INFO 165417 --- [nPool-worker-19] c.v.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerImpl    : Running webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
> ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:44019/webpack-dev-server/
> ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
> ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/X/Desktop/base-starter-spring-gradle-master/build/META-INF/VAADIN/webapp, src/main/webapp
>  [FlowIdPlugin] Serving the 'stats.json' file dynamically.
>
> ----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------
>
> 2021-11-01 16:44:07.266  INFO 165417 --- [nPool-worker-19]
> c.v.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerImpl    : Started webpack-dev-server.
> Time: 3305ms No issues found.

[IDE view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKKNA.png)

[problem output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPgbg.png)

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with a minimal example?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, I've just edited the post

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I highly recommend you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This will help you to improve the quality of your questions. **For every question, please show the attempts you have tried and the error messages you get from your attempts.** If you want to show your code, paste it as code, don't link to a screenshot. Same with error messages.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to access the app at http://localhost:8080/? I'm asking because the second screenshot you shared shows a different port than 8080.

Comment: @McPringle thank you. The problem I have is that there are no issues with the code. It compiles and runs successfully. The only way to show the problem I had was to share the output screenshot.

Comment: @TarekOraby thank you, Vaadin said the app was running on a specific host indicated so I just opened the link it provided. I will try to access localhost:8080 though.

Comment: @TarekOraby you were right. The message that Vaadin output was confusing!

Comment: Great, good to hear that it’s working okay.